# MapRoutes not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-routing

I can't see what is going wrong here. I have the more specific route on top but it just returns error 404 - not found.

Doing **/api/playernames/competitions** works but **/api/playernames/teams/competitionid/81bbd23d-54a2-4204-a771-85c48555a992** does not. What am I doing wrong?

```
routes.MapRoute("PlayerNamesDbTeams", "playernames/teams/competitionid/{competitionId}",
    new { controller = "playernames", action = "Teams", competitionId = "" });

routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "playernames", action = "Competitions" });


public class PlayerNamesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Competition> Competitions()
    {
        using (var service = new AggregatorClient())
        {
            return service.GetCompetitions();
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public List<Team> Teams(string competitionId)
    {
        using (var service = new AggregatorClient())
        {
            return service.GetTeams(competitionId);
        }
    }
}
```

Making a request like **/api/playernames/teams?competitionId=xxxxxx** does work.

Comment: Are you doing a GET to both URLs?

Comment: Yes... Although maybe I'm not sure what you mean. I have stated they are HttpGet methods.

Comment: /api/playernames/teams?competitionId=xxxxxx does work btw

Comment: I noticed that they're defined as HttpGet in the code - I just wanted to check that you were actually doing GET requests when you got the 404, that's all.

Comment: (You weren't using the second URL in a form with method POST, for example)

Comment: Nope, just trying to get it to work through browser for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using MVC routing; if you are using ApiControllers you should really use the WebApiConfig to define your routes.

Open up the `WebApiConfig.cs` in the `App_Start` folder and define your routes as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "PlayerNamesDbTeams",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/competitionid/{competitionId}",
    defaults: new { competitionId = "" }
    );
```